# TikTok return "Too many attempts. Try again later" when login with Selenium + C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to login TikTok with Selenium and C#, but when click `Log In button`, Tiktok return

> Too many attempts. Try again later.

Is there any way for me to fix it? I'd try many ways in another topics or some websites, but the problem is still not solved.

This is full function:

```
public string LoginTikTok(string user, string pass)
{
    new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
    var option = new ChromeOptions();
    option.AddArguments("--profile-directory=Default");
    option.AddArguments("--test-type");
    option.AddArguments("--disable-extensions");
    option.AddArguments("--disable-infobars");
    option.AddArguments("--disable-notifications");
    option.AddArguments("--enable-automation");
    option.AddArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options: option);

    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tiktok.com/login/phone-or-email/email");

    IWebElement userName = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_tikTokConfigSetting.UserNameXPath));
    userName.SendKeys($"{user}");

    IWebElement passWord = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_tikTokConfigSetting.PassWordXPath));
    passWord.SendKeys($"{pass}");

    IWebElement logIn = driver.FindElement(By.XPath(_tikTokConfigSetting.LogInButtonXPath));
    logIn.Click();

    return "OK";
}
```

[image: View image for more detail]
Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: You are being throttled. How frequently are you logging in?

Comment: I would suggest you to add a randon wait of 30-60 seconds before subsequent login. This should help you bypass the error message.

Comment: you should consider loading an already logged in user profile in selenium, in this way when you run `driver.get('https://tiktok.com/')` you will be automatically logged in